# Corona velocity of the objects

Tags: lua, physics, coronasdk

I'm trying to develop a game with Corona which consists of throwing some objects. However, to throw an object, all the objects must stop. I've implemented this by checking the velocities of all the objects in the field, If they're all zero then you're good to throw.

The problem is when you apply force to an object, it does not stop suddenly. Objects move very very slowly before stopping which leads to misinterpret the game. I mean you see that the object has stopped and try to throw another one but object actually hasn't stopped yet but moving very very slowly. Objects have a nice linear damping. How can I make a sudden stop for the objects?

I came up with a second implementation. I tried to use transition.to funciton which serves some really nice movements for objects, however this time objects don't collide with each other. Is there any way to enable physics in transition?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`physics.pause()`](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/physicspause) to pause the physics engine while the user throws the object (touches the screen), and then call [`physics.start()`](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/physicstart) to start it again when he lifts the finger, and apply force to the thrown object.